# Is it reasonable to use the Redux in the angular application?

Tags: angular, redux

At the moment, the question of using Redux in the angular application arises. However, there are doubts about the necessity and usefulness of this. There are many hierarchical structures in the application (sometimes more than 3 levels). The work might look something like this (using the ngxs, the code is simplified as much as possible):

```
export class SomeComponent {

  tableData: TreeTableData = new TreeTableData();
  //build TreeTableData for tree table view
  builder: SomeBuilder;
  public pageSize:number;
  public page:number;

  @Select(SomeState.state) state$: Observable<StateModel>;

  constructor(private store: Store) {
    //...
    //instantiate and configure builder
    //...
    this.state$.subscribe(patientState => {
        this.tableData = this.builder.build(state.items);
        this.restorePaginator();
        this.tableData.isLoading = state.loading;
      });
    this.builder.expandRowCallback = (row, tableData) => {
      ///...
      //dispatch that row is expanded
      ///...
    };
    this.builder.tableConfig.events.rowCollapsed = (row, tableData) => {
      ///...
      //dispatch that row is collapsed
      ///...
    };
  }

  private restorePaginator() {
    if(this.pageSize)
      this.tableData.pageSize = this.pageSize;
    if(this.page)
      this.tableData.page = this.page;
  }

  onPageNumberChanged(page:number) {
    this.page = page;
  }

  onPageSizeChanged(pageSize:number) {
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
  }
}
```

That is, in order to correctly restore the hierarchy (hiding / expanding rows) each time, it is necessary to notify the side. And this is only hiding / revealing strings, isn't using redux redundant in such a project?

Answer (score 1):

While Redux is the main way to share/maintain State in React, Angular offers Services to share and communicate the State within Components.

React library is mainly a Rendering library of JSX. To share and maintain State in ReactJS, libraries as NgRX were created. However Angular is a framework which provides ways to mantain/share/communicate State within Components.

So lets see what Redux provides:

> Redux is a pattern and library for managing and updating application state using events called “actions”. It serves as a centralized store for state that needs to be used across your entire application.

“Centralized Store” -> In Angular is called “Service”.

“State” -> Info pushed to the Subjects of the Service.

“Across your entire application” -> Dependency Injection of Services in the Constructors of the Components.

“Actions” -> Methods of the Service which pushes the info via “next” to your Subjects.

I would even add a small note: In Angular Services can be injected at Root so the Service is Global. Or you can inject at Component level so the Service is Scoped. You can fine-grain that with Angular Services.

A good Service architecture mimicks really closely the Redux approach  (or the Redux is following the Services approach maybe?):

1. Private Subjects
2. Public Subjects.asObservable
3. Public Methods to GET/POST to your Server   and/or modify Subjects.

Imho, 90% of Angular apps can be created with pure Services.

Answer (score 0):

Redux is not mandatory in every single application. If you think it's redundant, then it is.

To quote "[When should I use Redux?](https://redux.js.org/faq/general#when-should-i-use-redux)" (which applies to any other state management library):

> The need to use Redux should not be taken for granted.
>
> As Pete Hunt, one of the early contributors to React, says:
>
> "You'll know when you need Flux. If you aren't sure if you need it, you
> don't need it."
>
> Similarly, Dan Abramov, one of the creators of Redux, says:
>
> "I would like to amend this: don't use Redux until you have problems
> with vanilla React."
>
> In general, use Redux when you have reasonable amounts of data
> changing over time, you need a single source of truth, and you find
> that approaches like keeping everything in a top-level React
> component's state are no longer sufficient.
>
> ...
>
> *In the end, Redux is just a tool. It's a great tool, and there are
> some great reasons to use it, but there are also reasons you might not
> want to use it.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that using redux is not necessary, it is just a tool. But redux has many advantages [You Might Not Need Redux
](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367). I would like to know if there was an experience of unsuccessful use of redux (and, possibly, subsequent refusal) or an experience of deliberate refusal of redux?

Comment: Yes, there are many examples of both unsuccessful use, and of deliberate refusal. All those cases are a) anecdotal, b) don't mean they constitute truth (i.e. refusing in a certain example doesn't mean it is universally applicable) c) won't necessarily apply to your case. The way you phrased it in this comment, would be suitable to discussions on forums etc. As a general principle, it is suggested to go without it, until you realize Redux would make it easier for you, and add then. Regarding your original question, it doesn't seems like you need it (could be implemented with just RxJS/service).